# PDO access denied to external host, but I can access to phpmyadmin cp

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to connect to an external database through this script:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;dbname=dbname';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); 
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Regarding the data (host, username, database and password) everything is correct because when I tip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin on the browser and I enter the user and password it let me in to the database with permissions to create, delete and such.
But when I try to connect through PDO it gives me the "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Acess denied for..."

The information displayed on the PHPMYADMIN panel is as follows:
MySQL
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server version: 5.5.20
Protocol version: 10
User: user@localhost
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server
Apache
MySQL client version: 5.5.20
PHP extension: mysqli

Is it possible that I'm forced to use mysqli due to that "PHP extension: mysqli" property?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The information displayed on the PHPMYADMIN panel is as follows: MySQL Server: **Localhost** mind you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing seems wrong with your code except the `setAttribute` method is setting the error output to raise warnings.. but you're in a `try/catch` block.. so you may want to consider using `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

Secondly, check your remote permissions for that username/password. There may be an IP limitation for that user account. You can use the wildcard `%` for the `HOST` on user accounts or (suggested) provide the server IP that is connecting TO the database.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Unfortunately I can't do this myself so until the administrator contacts me I can't tell you if it went as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture a guess that phpmyadmin is working properly because phpmyadmin is on the host you're trying to connect to. My guess is that the server or user account is configured to only have access via 127.0.0.1/localhost - you can another record for the user you are trying to connect with and provide a wildcard or specific host for that user. Based on the information you've provided here, it seems like you'll just have to get MySQL setup to accept connections from other hosts.

Comment: Thank you very much! Once the administrator of that server tells me if that has been done I will tell you if this has worked!

Answer (score -1):

Meanwhile I've tried to run the application on local but it seems that it can't connect either, so maybe this can be of some help when it comes to identify the problem above.
This time (in localhost), the error is:
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxxxxx_xxxxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I created the user on my own phpmyadmin granting him all the permissions over this database, so I can't understand why even in localhost I can't connect to it. Can it be related to the problem above or is it something completely different that should go on a different topic? Thank you!